# Sharepoint Image Naming Convention

Tags: sharepoint

For my job I have to import large batches of images into the document library, I'm just wondering how people name their image files to keep it organized?

Comment: File name conventions heavily depends on application requirements, so I think this is a subjective question

Answer (score 0):

If it's an external facing site, name them something meaningful which ties in with the page title on which they are appearing. Name them something meaningful anyway and not something like img1, img2, etc.

Comment: is there a way to make sharepoint auto name the images? i'm just posting batches of 50 at a time and people don't really care about the name because they're put into folders...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the image name, just give them a guid as name, that way they are unique and to keep them organized you can use the metadata.